# How to sum values without knowing their key names in es6 (TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have this object. Keys are changeable. They are not fixed so I don't want to rely on `key`.

```js
interface Inf {
 [key: string]: number
}


const obj: Inf = {
  '2020-01-01': 4,
  '2020-01-02': 5,
}

const obj2: Inf = {
  '2020-01-05': 10,
  '2020-02-10': 15,
}

const finalObj = { one: obj, two: obj2, ... }
```

What I want to do is `sum` **10 + 15 + 4 + 5** regardless their key names. I have `lodash` installed and it has `sumBy` but it excepts input as array, however, mine is full object.

How can I get `34` in total with this object? Actually my question is half like What is the best way for doing such operation? I know I can do;

```js
let x = 0

Object.values(obj).forEach(o => {
   x += o
})
```

But is there a better way? Maybe shorter, faster?

Comment: *"I know I can do"* That version won't work, `o` will be an object reference, not a number. How flexible do you need to be? One level of objects? Two? As many as needed?

Comment: I've already fixed. `values` instead of `entries`. `finalObj` has 4 childs. Each child is like above.

Comment: I was talking about the fixed version. `finalObj`'s values are object references.

Comment: Ah! Sorry. Just one level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a recursive approach for nested objects.

```js
const
    add = object => Object
        .values(object)
        .reduce((s, v) => s + (v && typeof v === 'object' ? add(v) : v), 0),
    one = { '2020-01-01': 4, '2020-01-02': 5 },
    two = { '2020-01-05': 10, '2020-02-10': 15 },
    finalObj = { one, two },
    total = add(finalObj);

console.log(total);
```

Comment: This will be very useful for me to sum my other nested (3 levels) object however I just cannot add type casting. As I use TypeScript. I have to give `as any` to all objects: https://repl.it/repls/AppropriateFrenchPress#index.ts

Comment: `s` is always number.

Comment: still have to give `v` as any i guess. Because TS says `Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'number' and 'unknown'.ts(2365)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for sum. Works with only one level of objects like in your example.

```js
const obj = {
    "2020-01-01": 4,
    "2020-01-02": 5,
};
const obj2 = {
    "2020-01-05": 10,
    "2020-02-10": 15,
};
const finalObj = { one: obj, two: obj2 };

const result = Object.values(finalObj).reduce((a, b) => a + Object.values(b).reduce((a1, b1) => a1 + b1, 0), 0);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You've clarified in the comments that you're only dealing with a single layer (as shown in the question). I'd probably use a simple nested loop:

```
let sum = 0;
for (const obj of Object.values(finalObj)) {  // Loop through the objects
    for (const value of Object.values(obj)) { // Loop through the values
        sum += value;
    }
}
```

This is very like [Nikita's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63614847/157247), but keeping the loops explicit. :-)

Live Example:

```js
const obj = {
    "2020-01-01": 4,
    "2020-01-02": 5,
};
const obj2 = {
    "2020-01-05": 10,
    "2020-02-10": 15,
};
const finalObj = { one: obj, two: obj2 };

let sum = 0;
for (const obj of Object.values(finalObj)) {
    for (const value of Object.values(obj)) {
        sum += value;
    }
}

console.log(sum);
```